# trying to extract character string out of a line containing another character string using sed

Tags: sed, extract

I have a file that looks like this:

```
$variable['keyword1']   = 'value1';
$variable['keyword2']   = 'value2';
$variable['keyword3']   = 'value3';
$variable['keyword4']   = 'value4';
```

*keyword 1-4* are all unique and just letters and numbers.

*value 1-4* may or may not be unique and can be any combination of letters, numbers, special characters

I need to be able to extract *value1* or *value2* or *value3* or *value4* and save it as $somevariable. So the keyword is obviously the thing that I need to define in the sed command so that I get the desired value out.  How would I do that using an sed one liner?  Doesn't look that hard to me but I can't seem to crack it.  Been googling and trying different combinations for hours.

Comment: So you *only* want **value1** out of a file filled with different *values*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -n "s/\$\w\+\['keyword1'\]\s*=\s*'\([^']\+\)';/\1/p" inputfile
```

to save it:

```
somevariable=$(sed -n "s/\$\w\+\['keyword1'\]\s*=\s*'\([^']\+\)';/\1/p" inputfile)
```

if your file is exactly like you describe, you can also use this:

```
grep keyword1 inputfile | sed "s/.*=\s*'\([^']\+\)';/\1/"
```

or better yet: (thanks William)

```
sed "/keyword1/s/.*=\s*'\([^']\+\)';/\1/" inputfile
```

Comment: You nailed it.  Seems to work perfectly.  Never thought I would get an answer so fast.  Can't thank you enough. Yes the file is exactly as described but I would prefer to use sed since that is what I try use for all my scripting.

Comment: There is no need (*ever*) to pipe grep to sed.  Instead of `grep foo | sed 's/a/b/'`, do `sed '/foo/s/a/b/'`